# How to transform an object in a printable object in C++

Tags: c++, types

I would like to know how to print the value inside this object in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

void A::B(content::C* c) {
  cout << c << endl;
}
```

Currently the code above is only returning the memory address.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the format of the content?

Comment: Overload `operator<<`, which will allow you to do things like `std::cout << *c << endl;`

Answer (score 3):

The variable `c` is declared as a pointer:
`content::C* c`

To print the contents of `c`, you have to do two things:

1. Overload `operator<<` for `ostream`.
2. Dereference the pointer.

The above will allow a statement like:

```
cout << *c << endl;
```

There are a plethora of examples on overloading `operator<<`.

Alternately, you can write an output function that outputs each member.

The C++ has no standard facilities for outputting members of a `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Upvoted. Can step one be skipped if `C` is not a class but a built-in type? The OP doesn't specify what it is.

Comment: Yes, step 1 can be skipped for POD types, like `char, int, double`.  One of the major issues is that the pointer needs to be dereferenced.